# Close a file when multiple files open in OMEdit

Tags: openmodelica

I've just started to take a look at OpenModelica and I've been trying to get to grips with OMEdit. I currently have 2 files open (.mo files). Normally in an editor in this situation I can close a file by pressing the cross in the top right hand corner of the file, leaving only the other file in the perspective, but there isn't a cross     in this case, so I don't know how to get round this. I've tried looking at the user guide and googling 'OpenModelica close file', but haven't found anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found answer: just right-click on file name and click Close.